# Rails multiple views accessing controller with conditionals

Tags: ruby-on-rails, controller, action

I have a user model that includes shipping information in addition to the standard account information.

I have three different views that can update the user's information:

- Wizard
- Settings
- Account

I know that I should be using the REST model, so I'm attempting to run all of these updates through the Update action. The one catch is that in the Wizard view, I need to make a call to the Stripe API. So I have that Stripe call in the Update controller. But now when the user tried to update their account on the Settings or Account views, the update controller is calling the Stripe API, which obviously is not what I'm going for.

So what I've attempted to do, is to insert a conditional to check if one of the Wizard parameters(:total_value) is being passed in, and if it is, to charge to Stripe. If it's not, then just update the user data. But I haven't been able to get that to work, it's just updating the user and not charging to Stripe.

Is this the right direction to be separating these updates? Or should I be creating custom actions within the Users controller? How does this work?

**users_controller**

```
def update
  if !params[:total_value].nil?
    if @user.update_attributes(params[:user])
      # flash[:success] = "Profile updated"
      sign_in @user
      # Value input by the user (in dollars)
      @userPrice = params[:user][:total_value]
      # Send full price in cents to Stripe
      @stripePrice = @userPrice.to_i * 100

      Stripe::Charge.create(
        :amount => @stripePrice,
        :currency => "usd",
        :card => params[:user][:stripe_card_token],
        :description => "Charge for service"
      )  
      redirect_to success_path
      flash[:success] = "Hurray!"
    else
      flash.now[:notice] = "Can not be saved, please enter information."
      render :new
    end
  elsif 
    if @user.update_attributes(params[:user])
      sign_in @user
      flash[:success] = "Profile updated"
      redirect_to account_path
    else
      flash[:error] = "Error"
    end
  end    
 end
```

**wizard/show.html.erb**

```
  <%= form_for(@user) do |f| %>
  <%= render 'shared/error_messages', object: f.object %>
        <%= f.text_field :total_value, placeholder: "0", :class => 'amount' %>

        <%= f.label :name %>
        <%= f.text_field :name, required: "required" %>

        <%= f.label :address_1, "Address" %>
        <%= f.text_field :address_1, required: "required" %>

        <%= f.label :address_2, "Address line 2" %>
        <%= f.text_field :address_2 %>

        <%= f.label :city, "City" %>
        <%= f.text_field :city, required: "required" %>

        <%= f.label :state, "State" %>
        <%= f.text_field :state, required: "required" %>

        <%= f.label :zip, "Zip code" %>
        <%= f.text_field :zip, required: "required" %>

        <%= f.hidden_field :stripe_card_token %>

        <%= label_tag :card_number, "Credit Card Number " %>  
        <%= text_field_tag :card_number, nil, name: nil %>  

        <%= label_tag :card_code, "Security Code on Card (CVV)" %>  
        <%= text_field_tag :card_code, nil, name: nil %>  
       <%= label_tag :card_month, "Card Expiration" %>  
        <%= select_month nil, {add_month_numbers_true: true}, {name: nil, id: "card_month"}%>  
        <%= select_year nil, {start_year: Date.today.year, end_year: Date.today.year+15}, {name: nil, id: "card_year"}%>  
        <%= f.submit "Update your shipping information", class: "btn btn-large btn-primary" %>

    <% end %>
```

**users/shipping.html.erb**

```
      <%= form_for(@user) do |f| %>
        <%= render 'shared/error_messages', object: f.object %>
            <%= f.label :name %>
            <%= f.text_field :name %>

            <%= f.label :address_1, "Address" %>
            <%= f.text_field :address_1 %>

            <%= f.label :address_2, "Address line 2" %>
            <%= f.text_field :address_2 %>

            <%= f.label :city, "City" %>
            <%= f.text_field :city %>

            <%= f.label :state, "State" %>
            <%= f.text_field :state %>

            <%= f.label :zip, "Zip code" %>
            <%= f.text_field :zip %>  

            <%= f.submit "Update your shipping information", class: "btn btn-large btn-primary" %>
      <% end %>
```

**users/account.html.erb**

```
  <%= form_for(@user) do |f| %>
    <%= render 'shared/error_messages', object: f.object %>
        <%= f.label :name %>
        <%= f.text_field :name %>

        <%= f.label :email %>
        <%= f.text_field :email %>

        <%= f.label :password %>
        <%= f.password_field :password %>

        <%= f.label :password_confirmation, "Confirm Password" %>
        <%= f.password_field :password_confirmation %>

        <%= f.submit "Save changes", class: "btn btn-large btn-primary" %>

  <% end %>
```

Comment: In controller, you are checking for  if `!params[:total_value].nil?` . But should it not be `!params[:user][:total_value].nil?`

Comment: Yep. That did it! Thanks so much! I guess I'm misunderstanding how parameters work. (I'm new to this) Are you able to point me anywhere to learn more?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see two problems. First is that your:

`if !params[:total_value].nil?`

should be

`unless params[:user][:total_value].nil?`  (I personally prefer `unless` to `if !...`)

as stated in the comments by Nishant.  Second you have an `elsif` and the end of that condition, without it checking anything.  Just an `else` would suffice.